# Jquery DOM to reach Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have List of Products Displayed with in an Unordered List as Below.

[image]

When ever user is interested in Item they will Click I am Interested and I will change the background color along with tick mark of the item interested.

To make the tick mark appear i used a jquery function which gets called when i am interested is clicked

I have added the following line in the function to make the tick appear

```
<pre>                   $(this).parent().children(1).children(0).children(0).children(0).children(0).children(0).show();
</pre>
```

The whole jquery function is as below

```
<pre>
$(".checklist .checkbox-select").click(
  function(event) {         $(this).parent().children(1).children(0).children(0).children(0).children(0).children(0).show());           
}
);
</pre>
```

**I am Changing the Display of the Div which has the tick from none to block**

I want to know whether there is better way to navigate the DOM than coming through all the Children Node to reach the div which has Tick image

```
<pre>
    <li>
        <div style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;">
         <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="TickImgCont" style="display:none;">
            <img src="../templates/default/images/tick_white.gif" height="31" width="35"/>                  
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
             <div class="ImgContainerHeaderFont">Product Name</div>                      
             <div class="ImgContainerSubHeaderFont">Product</div>                        
            </td>
          </tr>
         </table>    
        </div>
        <div class="ImgContainer">
          <img src="../sample.jpg" height="150" width="200"/>
        </div>
        <div>
         <table class="PrefTblStyl" align="center">
           <tr>
            <td>Sample Text</td>
            <td>Sample Text</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Sample Text</td>
            <td>Sample Text</td>
           </tr>
         </table>
        </div>          
       <a class="checkbox-select" href="#" onclick="AddProjectId(1)">I Am Interested</a>
       <a class="checkbox-deselect" href="#" onclick="RemoveProjectId(1)">NotInterested</a>
    </li>
 </pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".checklist .checkbox-select").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.TickImgCont').show();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
  $(".checklist .checkbox-select").click(
    function(event) {
         $(this).closest('.TickImgCont').show());      
    }
  });

<li>
    <div style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;">
     <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="TickImgCont" style="display:none;">
        <img src="../templates/default/images/tick_white.gif" height="31" width="35"/>                  
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         <div class="ImgContainerHeaderFont">Product Name</div>                      
         <div class="ImgContainerSubHeaderFont">Product</div>                        
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>    
    </div>
    <div class="ImgContainer">
      <img src="../sample.jpg" height="150" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <table class="PrefTblStyl" align="center">
       <tr>
        <td>Sample Text</td>
        <td>Sample Text</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Sample Text</td>
        <td>Sample Text</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </div>          
   <a class="checkbox-select" href="#" onclick="AddProjectId(1)">I Am Interested</a>
   <a class="checkbox-deselect" href="#" onclick="RemoveProjectId(1)">NotInterested</a>
</li>
```

Comment: How do you get a `div` inside a `td` inside a `tr` inside a `table` to be a parent of the `a` element at the bottom ?

Answer (score 0):

A far better idea would be to create a seperate CSS class that has the styling of the box including the image of the tick. This way, you would only need to add the class instead of doing lots of jQuery calls.